# correlation plot in R grouped by two columns

Tags: r, correlation

[image: random data]

```
df <- data.frame (Name = c("adam", "adam", "adam", "brad", "brad", "brad", "chris", "chris", "chris", "abby", "abby", "abby", "lexi", "lexi", "lexi", "sarah", "sarah", "sarah"),
              job = c("doctor", "police", "doctor", "police", "doctor", "police", "doctor", "police", "doctor", "police", "doctor", "police", "doctor", "police", "doctor", "police", "doctor", "police"),
              price1 = c(43, 3, 6563, 44, 36, 5, 3, 546, 3, 24, 2, 4, 5, 58, 76, 46, 5, 3),
              price2 = c(0, 34, 43, 43, 34, 43, 354, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 5, 6, 4, 64, 5, 5),
              price3 = c(3, 2, 543, 533, 3, 55, 23, 235, 5235, 3, 23, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4)
             )

    > df
    Name    job price1 price2 price3
1   adam doctor     43      0      3
2   adam police      3     34      2
3   adam doctor   6563     43    543
4   brad police     44     43    533
5   brad doctor     36     34      3
6   brad police      5     43     55
7  chris doctor      3    354     23
8  chris police    546      5    235
9  chris doctor      3      4   5235
10  abby police     24      4      3
11  abby doctor      2      6     23
12  abby police      4      3      3
13  lexi doctor      5      5      4
14  lexi police     58      6      3
15  lexi doctor     76      4      3
16 sarah police     46     64      3
17 sarah doctor      5      5      4
18 sarah police      3      5      4
```

I am looking for an efficient way in R where i can get the correlation between the prices grouped by Name and job.

For example: I would like to get the correlation of price 1 and price 2 grouped by Name and job.

When I do cor(DF) it returns the correlation of all the prices but not grouped by the name and job, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions using both data.table and dplyr

```
dt = data.table(name = c("adam", "adam", "richard", "adam"),
                job = c("doctor", "police", "doctor", "police"),
                price1 = c(43, 50, 30, 40),
                price2 = c(0, 30, 10, 50),
                price3 = c(1, 20, 20, 20))


dt[, cor(price1, price2), by = .(name, job)]

tibble(dt) |> 
 group_by(name, job) |> 
 summarise(correlation = cor(price1, price2))
```